# Pymongo with altlas $ne doesn't exclude all documents

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I am using Pymongo to retrieve a collection and I need to exclude documents.
According the Mongo collection exclusion parameters, I used $ne in my query and I also excluded fields in my projection.

It seems not to work. I getting the documents with myVar set to true.

```
cursor = collection.find(
        { 'myVar' : { '$ne': 'true' }},
        { 
        'secret':  0,
        'Policies': 0
        }
        )
```

Notice my value is a boolean but if I do as written below I get an error :

```
{ '$ne': true }
```

Please help me experts ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses True/False for boolean operators, so you should use:

```
cursor = collection.find(
        { 'myVar' : { '$ne': True }},
        { 
        'secret':  0,
        'Policies': 0
        }
        )
```

The query seems fine, but you may also use the alternative approach as well:

```
cursor = collection.find(
        { 'myVar' : { '$in': [None, False] }},
        { 
        'secret':  0,
        'Policies': 0
        }
        )
```